# Get table Data from single table but from different paths

Tags: union

A greet to all Experts here at StackExchange.

The problem I have faced seems to be a simple one, it's just my low knowledge of SQL that unables me from doing it.

I have a Table called 'ApplicationPlans' with data about plans in each application of mine.
This table is connedcted to the 'Applications' table with ApplicationId as foreign key.
The 'Applications' is connected to the 'UserRoles' table once directly and once through the 'Clients' table. Allowing us to set access levels on the application level and/or client access level.

The figure can be seen [image: here]

My goal is to fetch data from 'ApplicationPlans' table for a user according to the roles he has.
Since this data is going to be in a grid, it's better that I dont use a UNION of two select queries like image [image: here]

of course that is my idea, you might say it works with same performance and I will do it.

So that was my situation,
Any suggestions is appreciated

- For sake of clearification I must add, 
  I need the those data from 'Applicationplans' which my user have access to. This is determined by first finding roles for this user and then in two phases:

  1. Find clients that this user have access to, then find their applications and then find their ApplicationPlans.
  2. Find Applications that this user have direct access to, then find ApplicationPlans that they have.

The result intended to be a union of these two sets together.

Comment: Can please clarify what the problem is?  What output do you want? What query have you tried? and what is the problem so far?

Comment: Thank you @Peter, I have added more details for clearification.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand what the problem is, but you can use a derived table like:

```
select ur.id, c.scopeid
from userroles ur
left join clients c
    on ur.scopeid = c.id
```

and then join that with the rest of the tables. Something like:

```
select ...
from (
    select ur.id, c.id as clientid, ...
    from userroles ur
    left join clients c
        on ur.scopeid = c.id
) dt
join applications a
    on dt.id = a.id
    or dt.clientid = a.clientid
join applicationplans ap
    on ap.applicationid = a.id
```

In general DDL (create table ..., etc) is preferred over images for describing tables.

Answer (score 0):

OKay, So far by searching around, I Found an answer and that was multiple Joins on a table, So far I wrote this query and this worked for me.

I would like to ask the moderators to edit this question to be a better guide for all the sql starters out there looking for simple matters like this!

And I Take this opportunity to thank all the guys who volunteered to help.

```
SELECT    
DISTINCT
   [ApplicationPlans].[Id]
  ,[ApplicationPlans].[Code]
  ,[ApplicationPlans].[Name]
  ,[ApplicationPlans].[UnsubscribeCode]
  ,[ApplicationPlans].[ThumbnailUrl]
  ,[ApplicationPlans].[ApplicationId]
  ,[ApplicationPlans].[Type]
  ,[ApplicationPlans].[IsActive]
  ,[ApplicationPlans].[ActiveUntil]
  ,[ApplicationPlans].[Description]
  ,[ApplicationPlans].[Price]
  ,[ApplicationPlans].[HasSubscription]
  ,[ApplicationPlans].[ExpireDays]
  ,[ApplicationPlans].[HasDebt]
  ,[ApplicationPlans].[DebtTarget]
  ,[ApplicationPlans].[DebtDays]
  ,[ApplicationPlans].[DebtStepDays]
  ,[ApplicationPlans].[DebtSleepDays]
  ,[ApplicationPlans].[DebtFinePrice]
  ,[ApplicationPlans].[CreditAmount]
FROM                    
Clients INNER JOIN
Applications ON Clients.Id = Applications.ClientId INNER JOIN
                     ApplicationPlans ON Applications.Id = ApplicationPlans.ApplicationId INNER JOIN
```

> UserRoles ON Clients.Id = UserRoles.ScopeId OR Applications.Id =
>   UserRoles.ScopeId

```
                     INNER JOIN (SELECT 3 as ScopeTypeId) AS ScopeSystem ON UserRoles.ScopeTypeId = ScopeSystem.ScopeTypeID
WHERE  UserRoles.UserId = @UserId
```